# SIGABRT after warning for setOn:YES - method not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uikit, uiswitch, sigabrt

for this line:

```
[UISwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
```

Xcode gives me a warning "class method not found (return type defaults to 'id')."

When I click on setOn or animated, the utilities pane recognizes it and says its declared in UIKit/UISwitch.h

UIKit is in my frameworks folder. I imported the .h to the .m like this:

```
#import "UIKit/UISwitch.h"
```

When I run, the main function receives "SIGABRT"

But when I remove that line above, no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because [`setOn:animated`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISwitch/setOn%3aanimated%3a) is not a class method. It is an **instance** method. You have to call this on an instance of `UISwitch`. For example:

```
// create an instance of UISwitch and add it to our view
UISwitch *onoff = [[[UISwitch alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:onoff];

[onoff setOn:YES animated:YES]; // should work normally
```